# Оставить не найденое значение в поле ввода vue-multiselect

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Использую компонент vue-multiselect. Когда произвожу поиск и значений не найдено, мне нужно сохранить это введенное значение, а оно автоматически удаляется после события blur multiselect. Как его сохранить введенным.
Возможно это можно реализовать какими-то другими библиотеками

Comment: можно прослушивать событие input и записывать ивент в свойство

Comment: Возможно вы подскажите как, в документации vue-multiselect не понятно как словить emit